# How to administer VMware ESXi from Linux?

Tags: vmware-esxi

I am experimenting with VMware's virtualization solution ESXi.
I got no problem installing the hypervisor, but now I wonder how to administer this thing.

As far as I found in the manuals there is the vSphere Client to do this job. But this client is not supported for Linux.

ESXi comes with a Web Client but only with version 6.x. With my old hardware I am only able to install a 5.1, so that's no solution as well.

I read about the vCenter. If I understand correctly this is an full-server image, so I need another machine for this? And to run it on a virtual machine inside ESXi does not work either, because I cannot create VMs.

---

Now I wonder if there is any way to administer VMware with a Linux computer?
I get the feeling VMware is not very Linux-friendly but only targets SysAdmins using Windows.

Answer (score 5):

5.1 is quite a problem to deal with via linux, ironically 6.x is fantastic for linux users, in fact vCenter 6.5 can be deployed directly form linux, and yes it runs as a VM, it's the default in fact. Also consider that 5.1 is end-of-support, basically 6.x sorts your problems but you have too old hardware, fix that not the other way around.